# Use *ngFor index to calculate animation delay

Tags: css, angular, angular5, ngfor

Could seem a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39399615/animation-delay-ng-repeat) question, but actually I am trying to affect the `animation-delay` property, not the animation timing itself.

I have an Angular template that creates list items by looping through them:

```
<div class="list-item" *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index" [attr.data-index]="i" style="animation-delay: {{ (i) + 's' }}"></div>
```

As you can see I already have the index and was hoping to use that to increment the animation delay on each element. But when I test in chrome, the style property isn't even computed, even though the index attribute is applied correctly. The animation, which I have specified in CSS, works fine, but the delay isn't applied:

```
.list-item {
  animation: appear 0.3s ease-out forwards;
}

@keyframes appear
{
  0%
  {
    top: 550px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  10%
  {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100%
  {
    top: 30px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: can you please share working example on stackblitz

Comment: @DanishArora We call it a [mcve]. Use `[mcve]` as shortcut ;)

Comment: @aloisdg Thanks for the suggestion!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try Using ngStyle Directive:

```
[ngStyle]="{'animation-delay': i + 's'}"
```

Hope that works well, If not , please share a working example on stackblitz